# Where can I find an example of a raw 1090ES message for testing?

Tags: ads-b

Can anyone provide a raw 1090ES Aircraft Operation status message (DO-260B standard) so I can test my decoding logic?

Comment: [Related](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/33235/62)

Comment: You may not see ADS-B callsign( mode s flight id) changed after completion of flight. I dont think that is something changes during flight, unless pilots are instructed to change to a default number. But even then, pilot might put transponder to stby mode and go silent before flight id change.